# Sending mails in Marmalade for the playbook and using libcurl

Tags: email, libcurl, marmalade, blackberry-playbook

I was doing a code for sending mails with the playbook and marmalade, this is my code

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587");
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, this->_PORT);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "xxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxxxxx");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, this->_FROM);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, this->_TO);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

It is the example from libcurl. (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html)

But everytime the curl_easy_perform executes i got the error **CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST** with every single address it does'nt matter if it is http,smtp, ftp, etc.

And if I put the IP instead of the name i always get Permission Denied.

I thing the error is the fake-ares.cpp and its asynchronous resolve.

I am using **libcurl 7.21.7** and **Marmalade 6.1**

Can anyone help me? :/ or is there another way to send mail?

Thanks

Comment: Does http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html work on your Playbook (just fetching a web page)?

Comment: Yes it works, I am using Marmalade, now I am having the problem in starting the SSL layer :/ I am using libcurl and openssl extensions for Marmalade.